# pygame, how to update the window size when resizing it

Tags: python, python-2.7, window, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a program with a pygame resizable window.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Since it is resizable, I want certain elements on the screen to change position and size in accordance to the window size.

I have all of my variables saved in the function setGet. I want the pass in the screen size and have all of the variables be dependent on that screen size passed in.

```
def setGet(screenSize):
```

I have a looping function that runs the command

```
setGet(screen.get_size())
```

The get_size() apperently doesn't get updated when you change the size of the window.

How can I update the size of the screen when resizing the window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I guess I found my own answer.

what you want to do is have resizing the window be an event.

so what you want is

```
if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
    setGet(event.size)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
changed = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            scrsize = event.size
            width   = event.w
            hight   = event.h
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(scrsize,RESIZABLE)
            changed = True
```

it's almost exactly like this in the comments for pygame.display.init doc page https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#comment_pygame_display_update
edited only slightly from 2011-01-25T23:10:35 - Dave Burton  thanks dave